# Income tax on international income with money not deposited in India

Tags: income-tax, india

I plan to have a consultancy business outside India. I do not plan to remit my income to India immediately. I would do it later maybe after 2 or 3 years. Do I need to pay taxes now? or can I pay tax when I bring the money into the country?

Answer (score 1):

If the work is done in India, then the income arising out of it, is taxable when received by you, and not when it come into India ...

Comment: And if the work is done elsewhere - the income is taxed at that elsewhere, unless a treaty says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

**Three points for you to keep in mind.**

**1.** In the very first year, you should have 182 days outside India. So that in the year when you start your consultancy, you will not have any liability to pay tax on earning abroad.

**2.** Although you may be starting a consultancy abroad, if you do any services in India, there will be withholding tax depending on the country in which you have started the consultancy business.

**3.** Whatever money you repatriate is not taxable in India. However, if you you repatriate the money as gift to anyone who is not a relative, will be taxed in his/her hand.

Comment: Again, I removed your advertising link. **Read the [section about self-promotion](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), and understand that what you're doing isn't acceptable here.**